# Can't find correct WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager

Tags: azure, storage, emulation

I am working on a project in school with Local Azure Storage and the teacher recommended using:

1. Installing Windows Azure Storage 2.1.0.4
2. Removing the errornous version Configuration Manager 1.8
3. Installing the correct and compatible version Configuration Manager 2.0.3

However I am getting a StorageException with 400(Bad Request).

I am using the correct syntax:

```
public CloudBlobContainer GetCloudBlobContainer()
        {
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("HiltiHaningePicturesBlobs");
            try
            {
                if (blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists())
                {
                    blobContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
                }
                return blobContainer;
            }
            catch (StorageException ex)
            {
                if (!(ex.Message == null))
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: I should also mention I cant find the ConfigurationManager in my GAC because the referenced version of the file displays version 2.0.0.0. So after installing 2.0.3 I get wrong version referenced somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the error you're getting is because of incorrect `WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager` class. More than likely this error is coming because of incorrect blob container name. Please try by changing blob container name to lower case letters. You may find this link useful for naming convention: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135715.aspx.

Comment: Worked like a charm....I who thought I was using correct syntax...pah! My ignorance is my downfall...thanks again good sir! :-)

Comment: Don't be so hard on yourself :) ... IMHO error messages should be self-explanatory which currently they aren't and hence all head banging :)